# Inherit from cv::Mat, a good idea?

Tags: c++, class, opencv, inheritance

I would like to extend the cv::Mat class with a few features (like serialization, taking ownership of data pointers, color ordering (rgb/bgr/...)).

One possibility is to create a new class (say CustomMat) that has a cv::Mat as a member:

```
class CustomMat {
  int width() { return m_mat.size().width; }
  int height() { return m_mat.size().height; }
  ...
  cv::Mat getMat() { return m_mat; }
  private:
  cv::Mat m_mat;
}
```

However, then I have to forward all constructors and members to use the outer class properly. Or I have to use something like `customMat.getMat().size().width`, which is also not very nice.

The alternative would be to inherit from cv::Mat directly:

```
class CustomMat : public cv::Mat {
...
}
```

This seems a bit fishy to me for a complex class like cv::Mat. Do you see any drawbacks or is this fine?

Comment: How would taking ownership of data pointers work? That sounds terrible... Why not just create a "data pointer wrapper `Mat`" (use constructor taking, well, a data pointer) and copy that into a new `Mat`? Serialization is hardly something that calls for a new class. And color ordering is already available from the `cv::Mat::type()` member function.

Comment: type only contains the bit depth and number of channels (for example CV_8UC3, which is three channels, unsigned int), but not the ordering (RGB? BGR?). I agree that for serialization it is not strictly needed. For data ownership: You can create a new cv::Mat with a data pointer as argument. However, you have to delete that pointer *outside* the cv:Mat again. I would like to give the data pointer to the cv::Mat and make sure that "delete[]" is called on it when the cv::Mat destructor is called.

Comment: Why do you have a raw data pointer anyways? Use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::vector` if you don't want to call `delete[]` yourself. A `cv::Mat` is always BGR. It would be best to convert to that when creating the `cv::Mat`, and not worry about it later.

Comment: Yes, but I would need some structure with the unique_ptr AND the cv Mat inside. Thats what I'm asking for in the question. Otherwise I have to pass the unique_ptr AND the cv::Mat to every function that uses it, which is horrible. And I don't always want to convert to BGR for performance reasons.

Comment: you can easily store the data elsewhere (in some scope so that it outlives the `cv::Mat`) and operate on only the `cv::Mat`. No need to expose the `unique_ptr` to the functions handlind the `cv::Mat`. It seems like `struct bla { cv::Mat image; bool rgb; private: std::vector<unsigned char> data; };` is all you need, with an appropriate initialization function to obtain the data from somewhere. Then you just pass `somebla.image` and to your work functions. Yes, maybe an extra argument for the `rgb` thing. Alternatively, let them accept a `bla&`, No need for 100's of getters and setters.

Comment: The point is this: Then I have to do bla.image.size().width, which is *exactly* what I don't want (as described in the question). I would like to pass bla to a function that can operate on it as on a "normal" image, calling width, height and so on.

Comment: one line in the function: `cv::Mat& real_image = bla.image;` will get rid of your extra redirection. On one size you want no big wrapper forwarding all properties, and on the other you want to add properties but not pass them separately, and aren't content with composition. These are your three options. No other way around this. Just pick one and write the code. Note that there are `cv::Mat::cols` and `cv::Mat::rows`, no need for `cv::Mat::size()`...

Comment: I would go with the inherited `cv::Mat`. It already has a reference counter to the data. By the way, `cv::Mat_` [is a subclass of](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=mat_#Mat_) `cv::Mat`.

Comment: I also thought of having a cv::Mat pointer and overloading the "->" operator...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a drawback by the inheritance approach. cv::Mat does not have a virtual destructor. That means, you might have troubles when using polymorphic behaviour for `CustomMat`. Take a look at the example below.

```
cv::Mat* foo = new CustomMat;
delete foo;
```

In the case above, destructor of CustomMat would never be called.

Answer (score 0):

What you try to do is not recommended. The drawbacks of such inheritance are many: slicing, need to forward all constructors, working with factories is hard. The recommended way in C++ of adding functionality to existing class is to create a set of global functions - best enclosed in a namespace - accepting `Mat` argument.

Comment: The point is that I would like to pass CustomMap around different (global) functions, exactly as you say. However, I don't want to give every function I work with the argument "rgb" or "bgr", I want to store this information inside the class. Also, I want to add some features, like a unique ID to every image. So your answer, though I agree, is a bit besides the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: In this case I think it is better to create a new class and store Mat as a member. `customMat.getMat().size().width` may be not very nice but it works and does not introduce hard to find problems.